# How to get device token in Js file from dart file?

Tags: flutter, dart, push-notification, token, device

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().functions);


var newData;

exports.messageTrigger = functions.firestore.document('Customer/{customerId}/{JobRequest}/{jobRequestId}').onCreate(async (snapshot,context)=>{
    if (snapshot.empty) {
        console.log('No Devices');
        return;
    }
    var tokens=['d3_HzzbR8vc:APA91bEKaQhKLU_Fd_dxxkLa88AW9G4fnsyRkp8XeNzdqipGfet5wVkvV0ZyOxlha5voSXGYCk0Fg0QIRx89Anytzev4kk7u1xo_zNiv_V1msYY-4Wct6pYfL05vMFoBN8qgbPOkscvj'];
    newData = snapshot.data;
    var payload = {
        notification: { title: 'Push Title', body: 'push Body', sound: 'default'},
        data: { click_action: 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION-CLICK', message: 'Sample Push Message'},
    };
    try{
        const response = await admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, payload);
        console.log('notification sent successfully');
    }
    catch(err){
        console.log('Error sending notification');
    }

});
```

here is my index.js file of FirebasCloudFunction, I want a different device token every time to send push notification from firebase , device token is also available in dart file variable, Is there anyway to get device token from dart file?

Comment: Are you trying to run a Dart script from a JS application or vice versa? Is this a snippet from your JS-powered API that you want to call from your Flutter app? It's extremely unclear what "get device token from dart file" means in this context.

Comment: there is only one JS file for firebase cloud messages function,  in which I required a user device token to send push notifications, but there will be different user every time,
In my flutter project I can get that token but I want to access that device token in JS file,
Is there any way to communicate between  dart and JS file?

Comment: If we are talking mobile Flutter, Dart and Javascript are two completely different runtimes that aren't directly compatible. There are ways to run one inside the other, but these are typically quite hacky and not recommended. If you are talking about HTML Flutter or dart2js, then you should check out the `dart:html` package for Dart-JS interop.